# Karate to Java call errors out with TypeError post upgrading from 0.9.6 to 1.0.1

Tags: upgrade, karate

My tests were written with karate 0.9.6 and now I am in the process of fixing some of the failed tests after upgrade to 1.0.1.

Calling a Java function using obtained api response raises an error.

Sample call in karate: obj.matchName(apiResponse, rName)

Sample Java method:

```
public String matchName(JSONObject apiResp, String name) throws Exception {
       try {       }
    catch (Exception e) {       }
    finally {       }
}
```

Error received:

obj.matchName(apiResponse, rName)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (matchName) on Utilities@a1b7549 failed due to: Cannot convert ''(language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsMap) to Java type 'net.minidev.json.JSONObject': Unsupported target type. - .:program(Unnamed:1)

This used to work well before the upgrade, could you please let me know how to handle this change with upgrade?

TIA

NT

Comment: I tried changing the Java method parameter to JSMap as well, but it still gives the same error - Cannot convert (language: Java, type: com.intuit.karate.graal.JsMap) to Java type 'com.intuit.karate.graal.JsMap': Unsupported target type.

Answer (score 0):

Karate never supported `JSONObject`, if it used to work - you were just lucky - so please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

So use a `Map`, `List` or `String` as parameter types.

If you are still stuck, follow the process - and note that old versions are not supported - as of now, the latest is 1.1.0: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: In the documentation, I'm seeing this tidbit: "Note that JSON gets auto-converted to Map (or List) when making the cross-over to Java." I am working now with an API response that is a json and wanting to pass it to a Java method to check the data in it. I tried setting both Map and List as the parameters for the java method but neither was being accepted, only a String. Is there any way of knowing why it is only being accepted as a String?

Comment: @AllisonCrenshaw most likely because it was defined as a string or because it is actually not (well-formed) JSON

Comment: I have been able to use the JsonPath filters such as * def temp = karate.jsonPath(cat, "$.kittens[?(@.name=='" + bob.name + "')]") to extract a piece of data from the json based on a given attribute's value. Given that, would you still say that the json may not be well-formed?

Comment: Also used karate.typeOf() on my json vars and they are showing as map in Karate, but not being accepted into Java as Maps.

Comment: @AllisonCrenshaw time for you to follow this process, thanks: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue